# How to uninstall summon-arm-toolchain?

Tags: software-uninstall

Recently I've cloned and installed summon-arm-toolchain from the git repository
[summon-arm-toolchain](https://github.com/esden/summon-arm-toolchain). After reading README file and do a little try outs with this toolchain I've seen that installed arm-none-eabi-gdb debugger doesn't work so good, and I've found that it might be a problem with the toolchain, solution of this problem will be installing new toolchain which is still supported [gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). My question right now is how can I uninstall obsolete toolchain ? Should I only remove all executable file which were installed in the /usr/bin folder ? The script itself doesn't support uninstall option. How would manage coexistence of those two toolchains which got the same targets ?

Comment: it depends upon how you have installed it ?

Comment: well, I've run the executable script named summon-arm-toolchain

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set to 'sudo' if you need superuser privileges while installing
SUDO=

PREFIX=${HOME}/sat
```

Apparently, if you didn't used `sudo` to install it, you just need to remove the `sat` directory. If you used `sudo` or changed the prefix, then just removing the directory should suffice.

The tool doesn't have uninstallation method.

Comment: I don't remeber did I used SUDO or not, but by running the `which arm-none-eabi-gcc` shows me that executable is in the `/usr/bin/` folder. In the folder `~/sat` I got folder named `arm-none-eabi` with some subfolders as include and libs.

Comment: @Lazureus well then, if it's in `/usr/bin` is almost sure 1) you used sudo; 2) which is lying (I prefer `type`); or 3) you installed something else that provides the binary. I'm installing it myself, lets see where it goes.

Comment: why `which` is lying ?:) the type output is the same. For sure I've installed this only through this package, unfortunately later I've noticed that it's not supported anymore.

Comment: @Lazureus everything got installed in the `~/sat` directory. Unless you remember how you installed it, you are alone :(

Comment: could you tell me only which version of the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` does it install ? Maybe I'll just remove or move somewhere the `/sat` directory and binaries from the `/usr/bin`